# Error: Installation did not succeed. The application could not be installed in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, configuration

I am new to android studio. And the app on which I am working was not giving the installation error with the last code change. Once I add another line of code, I start getting error:

```
Timed out waiting for the process (com.iab.omid.sampleapp) to appear on 

Pixel_3a_API_32_arm64-v8a [emulator-5554].
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.

List of apks:
[0] '/Users/mukul/Documents/jivox/jivox-android/omsdk-android-1.3.31-Jivox/OM-DemoApp/build/intermediates/apk/defaults/debug/OM-DemoApp-defaults-debug.apk'
Installation failed due to: ''cmd package install-create -r -t --user current --full --dont-kill -r -t --skip-verification -S 10540209' returns error 'Unknown failure: Exception occurred while executing 'install-create':
android.os.ParcelableException: java.io.IOException: Requested internal only, but not enough space
```

The app is still opening and it seems like the newly added code is not reflected there. (not sure about this).

How can I fix this issue?

Please let me know if more details are required from my side.

Comment: "but not enough space". that seems to be your problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your emulator has ran out of space.

1. You can clear space by wiping the data
2. You can add more space by going to advanced settings in AVD popup